# How do I code app-to-app direct communication on different devices?

Tags: ios, instant-messaging

I have developed an IOS app in swift. Currently messages from app-to-app is done via sending to middle app server using REST APIs, and then the other device polls for the message. I'm wondering how to avoid the middle-man and sending messages directly to another device using the same app. I've seen plenty of text/messaging tutorials in swift and they all use the sms interface where they pop open the device native text messaging app to send (which would then be received by the native messaging app, not my app). That isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I want the app itself to send the message directly to the same app on another device. I was thinking that tokens were possibly the way to go (like push notifications), but I'm not certain that's the right way either. Is this where firebase comes in? Just looking for the right keywords to find the right tutorial, different than the ones I've already found that are not quite doing the job.

Thanks in advance for the direction.

Comment: "Is this where firebase comes in" - that's another central server.

Comment: Overall, your two devices need to discover each other somehow. I don't know how to do that without _some_ kind of a central server. If one or both devices are behind NAT, things get more complicated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do peer-to-peer communication in an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909809/how-to-do-peer-to-peer-communication-in-an-iphone-app)

Comment: *"and then the other device polls for the message"* - don't poll. Use push notifications.

Comment: @HangarRash  - I could use a push notification, but what if the token stored changes? My app will save its token when it starts, but if the user doesn't start the app it isn't updating its token and may not receive the message then. Thoughts?

Comment: I also want to mention that I could use SMS, I just don't want to pop up the default message app to send the message, and I don't want the recipient's default messaging app to receive the message. I want app-to-app communication. Think of how WhatsApp sends messages to "its" app, not the default messaging app. That's what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @JimWartnick All of that requires a central server to receive messages from each user and to send push notifications out to intended recipients.